# Is there any way to autogenerate fields in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using intellij / android studio and I see I lost so much time to generate new fields. So I thought maybe there is any way to auto generate all new fields..

[image]

My fast way is:

1. select red field
2. left alt + enter
3. arrow down
4. enter
5. enter
6. ctrl + alt + arrow left

Is there any other way to make it faster by selecting few not declared fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many quick fixes, there is a side menu option to "Fix all xyz problems in file". This is however not available when fixing a "Cannot resolve symbol 'foo'" error since there are multiple ways to solve such an issue (i.e. add a field, a local variable, a parameter, etc.)

**The fastest way would be to auto generate the names and fields as you write the code.** This also has the advantage that when you use a variable name suggested by IDEA, you save even more keystrokes. Moreover, those variables/fields are immediately available for code completion.

For example, for the first item you show, I would do the following:

1. Type: `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourNick);`

   - Notice there is no leading variable/field name or `=` sign
2. With the cursor still at then end of the line (i.e. to the right of the closing `;`) Use the *Introduce Field* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) action.
3. Either select one of the suggested names or type a name, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The cursor ends where it was (i.e. the end of the line), so you can just type <kbd>Enter</kbd> and continue coding the next line. This methodology adds only a single key stroke (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), but eliminates typing of the `=` and 2 spaces (so you are ahead 2 keystrokes). And it can eliminate typing the variable/field name if one of the suggestions is useable (which is very often is).

The same works for local variable names (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), "constants" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), and parameters (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

I use this methodology constantly. I can't remember the last time I have ever manually started a line of code with a variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

1. select red field
2. ctrl + alt + F  (Extract field)
3. enter

Comment: I am talking about mass creating fields - not single

Comment: How is f2, ctrl alt f, enter not quick enough for you? It honestly takes 0.25 seconds per field. If you want a magic button, write yourself a plugin.